# What is the topology on $[0,1]$ for a continuous $f$ in the Tychonoff spaces?

Tags: general-topology

Following a reference from "General Topology" by Ryszard Engelking

[image]

Well in definition of *Tychonoff space* I don't understead what is the topology on $I\equiv[0,1]$: what would be the topology on $[0,1]$ that transforms $f$ into a continuous function? claiming that $[0,\frac{1}2)$ and $(\frac{1}2,1]$ are open set of $[0,1]$ it means that the topology on $[0,1]$ is the subspace topology of the Euclidean topology on $\mathbb{R}$?

Could someone help me, please?

Comment: $I$ is an abbreviation Engelking uses for $[0,1]$ *in the Euclidean topology*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, certainly. The topology on $[0,1]$ is the one induced by the usual topology on $\mathbb  R$.

Comment: Or equivalently, the order topology from its natural order.

Comment: @Henno Brandsma Hello, professor! So I could reformulate the definition of *Tychonoff space* as following: «A topological space $X$ is called *Tychonoff space* if it is $T_1$ and if for every $x\in X$ and every closed set $F\subseteq X$ such that $x\notin F$ there exists a function $f:X\rightarrow [0,1]$ such that is continuous **using the subspace topology of the Euclidean topology on $[0,1]$** and such that $f(x)= 0$ and $f(y)=1$ for $y\in F$», right?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. When  Mathematicians treat subsets of Euclidean spaces as topological spaces without mentioning the topology they always assume that the topology is inherited from the usual topology of the corresponding Euclidean space. @AntonioMariaDiMauro

Comment: @AntonioMariaDiMauro Yes, the topology on $[0,1]$ is always taken to be that, unless specifically mentioned otherwise... The order topology happens to be the same as the subspace topology, and $[0,\frac12)$ is a subbasic order open set, e.g. Just for extra info.

Comment: Okay, now it is clear: thanks!